# How to call a list loaded with text (data) to each instance of class

Tags: c#

I'm working on a hotel management program and i'm loading a list of articles that belong to a minibar.
So I have a List on a .txt file,and that list must be part of each instance of a class,then every instance of each class is loaded with another .text file, also on the main program. How do I make each instance of that class 
 has that list loaded before

I've already tried naming it from the constructor of the class but it wont let me access

```
class Ejecutiva:Habitacion
{
    private List<MiniBar> articulosminibar;

    public Ejecutiva(int nrohabitacion, string tipocama, int cantcama,
        bool estadodisp, int preciohabitacion) : base(nrohabitacion,
            tipocama, cantcama, estadodisp, preciohabitacion)
    {
        this.articulosminibar = ???? ;
    }

    internal List<MiniBar> Articulosminibar { get => articulosminibar;}

}
```

```
class program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string linea;
                string[] destino_split;
                MiniBar miniBarEjecutiva;
StreamReader archivo = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\Desktop\\semestre5\\Poo\\ArchivosHotel\\MinibarEjecutiva.txt");
                linea = archivo.ReadLine();
                while(linea != null)
                {
                    destino_split = linea.Split('|');
                    miniBarEjecutiva = new MiniBar(destino_split[0], int.Parse(destino_split[1]), int.Parse(destino_split[2]), int.Parse(destino_split[3]));
                    MinibarEjecutiva.Add(miniBarEjecutiva);
                    linea = archivo.ReadLine();
                }

List<MiniBar> MinibarEjecutiva = new List<MiniBar>();
 Ejecutiva ejecutivas;
                List<Ejecutiva> listaejecutivas = new List<Ejecutiva>();

StreamReader archivo5 = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\Desktop\\semestre5\\Poo\\ArchivosHotel\\Ejecutivas.txt");
                linea = archivo.ReadLine();
                while (linea != null)
                {
                    destino_split = linea.Split('|');
                    ejecutivas = new Ejecutiva(int.Parse(destino_split[0]), destino_split[1], int.Parse(destino_split[2]),
                        Convert.ToBoolean(destino_split[3]), int.Parse(destino_split[4]));
                    listaejecutivas.Add(ejecutivas);
                    linea = archivo.ReadLine();
                }
```

Comment: What do you want to load before? Load the list before using the instances? Load the file before creating the instances?

Comment: load the file before creating the instances :(

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly. Can you open the file and load the list right before the `new Ejecutiva(...)` statement?